# Calling Promise with Axios in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

How to implement Promise in this Axios POST request for Vue-Snotify?
This is my Axios post request:

```
const url = 'https://foobar.api/photos';
axios.post(url, {photo: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + photo})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.info('Done');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

This package [Vue-Snotify](https://artemsky.github.io/vue-snotify/documentation/) I want to add as a notifier what will show a notify box with a loader showing the progress. This is what it should look like regarding the docs:

```
this.$snotify.async('Called with promise', 'Success async', () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve({
    title: 'Success!!!',
    body: 'We got an example success!',
    config: {
      closeOnClick: true
    }
  }), 2000);
}));
```

But how to achieve this? I'm no pro in Vue and can't figure out how to combine those two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return axios to accomplish this but if you catch the error Snotify will show a success message. Try this:

```
this.$snotify.async('Called with promise', 'Success async', () => {
    const url = 'https://foobar.api/photos';
    return axios.post(url, {photo: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + photo})
        .then(function (response) {
            console.info('Done');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error first

            throw error;
        });
}));
```

EDIT: If you want to control the messages to this instead:

```
 this.$snotify.async('Called with promise', 'Success async', () => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const url = 'https://foobar.api/photos';
     return axios.post(url, {photo: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + photo})
     .then(function (response) {
       resolve({
         title: 'Success!!!',
         body: 'We got an example success!',
         config: {
           closeOnClick: true
         }
       })
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       reject({
         title: 'Error!!!',
         body: 'We got an example error!',
         config: {
           closeOnClick: true
         }
       })
     });
   });
 });
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qo6fdv1n/2/

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to remove the notifiers after a while? Docs dont speak about it @eduardo-aguad

Comment: @user1469734 I found in the docs the ``timeout`` config. Try this setting ``timeout: 1000;`` in config, and remove ``closeOnClick``

Comment: @EduardoAguad Hi! How can I do something when success or error? I try to use my vue functions before resolve, but got an error.

Comment: @autumnrustle axios return a promise, you can handle error and success with that promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise